# DietPI: _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

i want to run a python script on dietPI. I chose dietPI because i want to boot fast.

When i run a simple tkinter program i get the error  `_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable`
Ive already tried setting a display variable like so: `export DISPLAY=:0` 
(i tried other numbers aswell)

but then i get `_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0.0"`

Any help?

Comment: Maybe it doesnt support to launch GUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This took me all day to get working. (I also posted this same answer on a different SE site here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/118928/60683)

**Note: This is for raspbian, with main user account using the default username ("pi")**

Here are the steps in order:

---

Name your python file `main.py` and drag your python file to the desktop.

---

Next, create a new plain text file and add the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

python3 /home/pi/Desktop/main.py
```

Save this text file as `launch.command` on the desktop. This is shell script to launch your python file. By default it won't work, we have to chmod it (next step)

---

Run terminal and run the following command:

```
chmod u+x /home/pi/Desktop/launch.command
```

Now double clicking launch.command (and selecting `execute`) will launch your python file.

---

At this point, we are ready to get it launching on boot. **If you've done any other launch attempts prior to this please undo all of those file changes you had done**.

---

Open terminal and run the following:

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/myproject.service`

*We are just going to call it myproject for now, don't change any of this until after you get it working, then feel free to attempt a rename*

---

In the window that pops up, copy paste the following exactly:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start Myproject
After=graphical.target
Wants=graphical.target

[Service]
User=pi
Group=pi
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "export DISPLAY=:0; export XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority; /home/pi/Desktop/launch.command"

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Now press ctrl+x to exit-and-save, it will prompt you to save changes, type "y", the filename should already be entered as .../myproject.service, if it is then press enter and it will save and exit, *if the file name is blank it messed up (this just happens sometimes), quit terminal and try all of this again, sorry.*

---

Now in terminal enter:

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

Then

`sudo systemctl enable myproject.service`

Lastly

`sudo reboot`

---

On launch, before anything else shows (after the boot up splash screen shows of course, but before desktop shows) your GUI will now launch, congrats!

I recommend you launch it full screen, to do that edit your python file to use this:

```
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
```

**NOTE, 'root' is likely not what you called your TK() init.... at the end of your code you have something like `XXXX.mainloop()`, change 'root' to whatever XXXX is, stick this right after your init of `TK()`**

---

Once you've reboot, you are likely stuck in the app (especially if you launched it full screen), things like alt+f4 or alt+f11 won't kill your program. To exit, press the windows/menu button on your keyboard, the access panel will appear you and can go to accessories>terminal to launch a new terminal window, then run the following:

`sudo systemctl stop myproject.service`

The program will be killed and you will be back to your standard desktop...

NOW, to prevent it from launching again on bootup, simply rename your `launch.command` file to `DISABLED_launch.command` and when you're ready to start launching on bootup again set the name back.

---

Go get a drink, you've earned it.

*Also, you can obviously put these places other than desktop but MAKE SURE you always use the full path in any of these commands, don't use the '~/..' shortcut.*